# Django reverse URL breaks in production

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-views, production-environment

I'm running into `Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` This occurs for a view that takes no arguments, and is named, with and without quotation marks in the template. It only happens on my production server, not my dev environment. Both run Django 1.4.

I have the following entry for an argument-less view in my top level `urls.py`.

```
url(r'^course_catalog/', include('course_catalog.urls')),
```

In `course_catalog/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('course_catalog.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name="home"),
    ...
```

I also have the following in a couple of templates

```
<a href="{% url home %}">
```

I've also tried this in the `manage.py` shell:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('home')
'/course_catalog/'
```

So it seems to only happen when the template is served or something. 
The view itself works, by the way, if I navigate to the URL.

I don't really know where to look at this point.

Any idea what could be causing this to happen? Thanks!

Comment: Can't WSGI deployment affect this? (diffent Python paths than in shell, script alias paths, ...)

Comment: I think I've got things set up properly, since the site will load if I comment out out the URL lookups. But I have very little experience with WSGI and associated tech, so there's a good chance I'm wrong! What sort of setting would give them different paths?

Comment: I thought that when you're running manage.py shell, your current directory is the project dir, which means that Python will find modules that might not be discoverable in you WSGI Python path settings. Which may or may not be related to what you're experiencing. Another thing I'd try would be actually rendering the template in your python shell, via `django.template.loader.render_to_string`.

Comment: Hmm. Rendering the template that way works fine. So that suggests path issues I guess?

Comment: Well, this is the only thing I can come up with right now :-) You might try adding `import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/project/dir')` to the beginning of your WSGI file.

Comment: Ok. I'll mess around with that. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18474/discussion-between-che-and-chris-cooper)

Answer (score 1):

> Reverse for ''home'' with arguments '()'

It seems like you are doing `{% url 'home' %}` in a template that doesn't have `{% load url from future %}`. That would explain why django double-single-quote `''home''`. Like if you were doing `reverse("'home'")`.

Comment: Oops, I edited my question to reflect the change in the template line, but forgot to update the error. It shows the actual error I get now.

Comment: I originally had that and was using quotation marks, but I abandoned it and went back to straight 1.4 in an effort to simplify things and find the error.